# Newest tweets on tweepy for python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to find tweets containing a certain word, but I want to just get the newest tweets from the last five minutes up. How would I go about this? This is my code at the moment.

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "**********"
consumer_secret = "**********"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token("**********", "**********")

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search(q = "", since = "2015-09-26", language = "EN")
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: I edited your post to remove your credentials, I would suggest you get new ones from twitter and never share them again.

Also change your `api.search` (Rest API) to the [Streaming API](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html?highlight=stream). This will give you a portion of tweets that match your criteria for the moment you open that connection.

*For example*

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener

consumer_key = '****'
consumer_secret = '****'
access_token = '****'
access_secret = '****'


class Listener(StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):

        try:

            print(str(status.text.encode('utf-8')))

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print(status_code)


while True:
    try:
        auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
        twitterStream = Stream(auth, Listener())

        twitterStream.filter(q=['python'])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: How would I display the tweets? This is the code I have now:

`consumer_key = ""``consumer_secret = ""
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
myStreamListener = MyStreamListener()
myStream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=myStreamListener)
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token("", "")
print (myStream)`

Comment: `print(status.text)` is displaying the actual tweet. Remove `print(myStream)`. Are you not receiving anything?

Comment: Try the code above, that's the one I use myself and works. `print(str(status.text.encode('utf-8')))` should hopefully deal with any encoding problems you might encounter. `print(status_code)` will print any code received from twitter listed [here](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/response-codes)